# Determine smallest possible parameter set for FPT

Tags: complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity

I am reading a book about complexity analysis and cannot find a way to solve a problem in that book.
The problem is, that I do not understand how to determine the smallest possible parameters, given the runtime of an algorithm. Do I just need to insert some numbers and see if the parameters exceed n at some point? Perhaps someone can explain that to me.

Consider the following exercise:

> The following O(.) expressions represent worst-case runtimes of different algorithms, where n is a measure of the input size and p, q and r are parameters (where p, q, r <= n). Which of the following running times are FPT running times?
>   Give the smallest possible parameter set for which the running times are FPT (if one exists) and explain.
>
> a) $O(p^q * n^2)$

Now I know that by the definition of FPT, this runtime is FPT (because we have a function of the parameters times n^constant). However, what are the smallest $p$ and $q$ in that case?

There are some more, but I just want to understand how to solve it and then I'll try the rest myself again.

Taken from:

> Rooij, I. V., Blokpoel, M., Kwisthout, J., & Wareham, T. (2019). Fixed-Parameter Tractable Time. In Cognition and Intractability: A Guide to Classical and Parameterized Complexity Analysis (p. 125). Cambridge, England: Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the runtime must be of the form $f(k) \cdot n^c$ for some constant $c$. So I believe that the exercise is asking, given that all three are at most $n$, which do you have to take as formal parameters in your analysis to achieve an FPT runtime.

So if only $p$ is a parameter, is that FPT? What if only $q$? Clearly, if both are fixed, you have FPT runtime.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I really did not understand that from the exercise. That makes it a lot easier for me. I thought I really had to calculate the parameters.